# vb.net Refresh DatePicker value after everyday

Tags: vb.net, datetime, refresh, datetimepicker

I have this code under a Timer's tick event to refresh the value of a DateTimePicker after everyday/at 7:19 (tTmNow)
`Private Sub tmrNewDay_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrNewDay.Tick

If tTmNow.Text.Contains("7:19:") Then 'at this time pick yesterday's date

```
        Dim ystd As String
        ystd = Today.AddDays(-1) 'yesterday
        dtPicker1.Value = ystd    'put yesterday's date into the date time picker

    End If

End Sub`
```

Unfortunately, at the first run of the program, I achieve my aim successfully. But the second day (The program is to run everyday and pick yesterday's date), when picking the date, it adds the time; giving **19-04-2017 00:00:00**, instead of **19-04-2017**. Is there a way to refresh the contents of the DateTimePicker or is there an entirely new way of picking yesterday's date, day after day.

Comment: A `DateTime` _always_ has a time component.  If you only want to display the date portion, then set the custom format property on the `DateTimePicker`

Comment: You should turn on `Option Strict`

Comment: You do not need to and should not convert `Today.AddDays(-1)` to a string which as Plutonix mention would not be allowed with Option Strict On without add a `.ToString()` or `.ToLongDateString()`. `Today.AddDays(-1)` returns a DateTime and your `DateTimePicker.Value` is a DateTime Field, so this would work and is way cleaner `dtPicker1.Value = Today.AddDays(-1)`

Comment: Also I am assuming this is winforms and not WPF. What properties do you have set on the DateTimePicker?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway for the DateTimePicker's Customformat property, how do I set it under the properties tab? I write yyyy-MM-dd, dd/MM/yyyy and all get rejected as invalid properties...

Comment: @Plutonix How do I turn on `option strict`. I don't have the slightest idea on how to do that.                                                                                   @plutonix thanks for being helpful to me many times.

Comment: Yes @KellyBarnard it is Windows Forms. I am completely lost with what you're saying. Can you write down the code for me?

Comment: You need to set the `Format` property to "Custom" and then set the `CustomFormat` property to the desired format.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway. That was done some time back. It doesn't work.     Do you have any idea as to how I will go about @Plutonix 's `Option Strict` Approach?

Comment: @MordC What I was saying in my comment it that you could replace all three lines of code in your example with just `dtPicker1.Value = Today.AddDays(-1)`

Comment: Oo ok. Kelly. Thanks. @KellyBarnard. Can you help with Plutonix's `option strict` approach?